# Java EE, local server error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I'm working on a project on my local machine, attached is an image of the error I've been stuck on for awhile now.

[image: error]

I've updated my computer to have jdk 1.8 but Netbeans still seems to think I'm on 1.7...

Comment: Did you set your system's `JAVA_HOME` variable to the java 8 directory? You can check by using `echo $JAVA_HOME`. You might also have to change some netbeans build path settings.

Comment: how do I change anything in this terrible IDE? nothing but problems.